# Django login system

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a "ready" example of a Login/Register/Authentication system for my site written in Python (so with Django I suppose).

**EDIT:**

I've tried the Django-registration, [see this tutorial](http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/)

In the tutorials (see STEP 4), I need to update the file urls.py to:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
    (r'^$', direct_to_template,
            { 'template': 'index.html' }, 'index'),
)
```

But when I do this, the Admin page is not available.
When I chance

```
(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.urls)
```

instead of

```
(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root)
```

When I do this, I could login to the Admin page, but I couldn't click on anything...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)) if you are using Django 1.3. If this is a new question, which it rather is, the convention is to ask a **new** question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration

> This is a user-registration application for Django. There are two registration workflows (one-step, and two-step with activation) built in, and it's designed to be extensible and support building additional workflows.

Comment: Thanks! Only a problem with my Admin-page, see my post-edit please :)

Answer (score 1):

Try django-registration or [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/).